# Select Column as Column names of values in another table in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need help on a getting my column names as values in another table in SQL 2008.

### For Example

### Table A

```
Type     Col1      Col2      Col3     Col4      Col5

101      1         2         3        2         5
102      4         2         3        2         0
103      2         1         0        0         5
103      7         2         0        0         5
105      8         3         0        0         0
```

### Table B

```
ColID        ColName

Col1         Math
Col2         English
Col3         French
Col4         Fine Arts
Col5         Biology
```

So basically the Table B holds the column name to be used when selecting from Table A
Such that, if i want to do a sample code like

```
Select Col1,Col2,Col3 from TableA
```

It should look like

```
Select Col1 as Math, Col2 as English, Col3 as French from Table A........
```

Did all i could but could not get any code giving me what i want....

Need help.

Note*
Reason i designed the table like this is because the column names can change very frequently by user and instead of having to alter code everytime, this should work no matter the changes made to column names when i export to excel.

Comment: You will have to use dynamic here.

Comment: Or if possible redesign this so the Col values are down (rows) not across (columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this done with your current design you will have to use dynamic SQL. I wont go into the pros and cons of dynamic SQL here. For more info you can go [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). I highly suggest reading up on it if you are not familiar with dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (Type int, Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int, Col4 int, Col5 int);

CREATE TABLE #TableB (ColId varchar(50), ColName varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES
(101, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5),
(102, 4, 2, 3, 2, 0),
(103, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5),
(103, 7, 2, 0, 0, 5),
(105, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0);

INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES
('Col1', 'Math'),
('Col2', 'English'),
('Col3', 'French'),
('Col4', 'Fine Arts'),
('Col5', 'Biology');

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX);

/*   Build SELECT   */
SET @Sql = 'SELECT ';

SELECT @Sql = @Sql + ColId + ' AS ''' + ColName + ''', ' FROM #TableB;

/*   Remove trailing comma   */
SET @Sql = (SELECT LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@Sql)-1));

/*   Add FROM   */
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM #TableA';

/*   Output query   */
SELECT @Sql;

/*   Execute query   */
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;

DROP TABLE #TableA;
DROP TABLE #TableB;
```

Comment: thanks so much. Using that code within SQL seemed to work, but i could only verify if it would work for me from VB6. How do i make this code work within VB6 ?

Comment: @TobyyDamian This is SQL specific question which has been anwered. You may want to now post a new question with your issues within VB6. I cannot help you with VB6. My only other suggestion would be to turn this into a stored procedure that you can call. That would make implementation into your app easier most likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute dynamic query, in which you are replacing the aliases with the configured column names. You can do it with code like this:

```
use [tempdb]
go

drop table if exists TableA
drop table if exists TableB

create table TableA([Type] int, [Col1] int, [Col2] int, [Col3] int, [Col4] int, [Col5] int)

insert into TableA values
(101,      1,         2,         3,        2,         5),
(102,      4,         2,         3,        2,         0),
(103,      2,         1,         0,        0,         5),
(103,      7,         2,         0,        0,         5),
(105,      8,         3,         0,        0,         0)

create table TableB(ColID sysname, ColName sysname)

insert into TableB values
('Col1',         'Math'),
('Col2',         'English'),
('Col3',         'French'),
('Col4',         'Fine Arts'),
('Col5',         'Biology')


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select [Type], [Col1] as [{Col1}], [Col2] as [{Col2}], [Col3] as [{Col3}], [Col4] as [{Col4}], [Col5] as [{Col5}] from TableA'

-- Execute unmodified query
exec sp_executesql @sql

-- Replace aliases with column names
select @sql = REPLACE(@sql, CONCAT(N'{', ColID, N'}'), ColName)
from TableB

-- Execute query with replaced aliases
exec sp_executesql @sql

-- Cleanup
drop table if exists TableA
drop table if exists TableB
```

Comment: OP is using SQL Server 2008 so `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` will not work.